# Power of a specific signal

Tags: power, power-electronics

I have this output signal (attached) where I am trying to work out:

1. The instantaneous Power
2. The average power

However, I am a little bit stuck and don't quite understand how to go about doing this. Could someone point me in the direction of the calculation and how to solve the equations if possible (maths isn't my strong point). The exact answer is not necessary; a ball park figure and the method used to calculate will be more than useful. If I wanted a piece of equipment to calculate the Voltage RMS and Current RMS what would be a good choice?

Channel 1 is the yellow signal and is the voltage. They are 10V increments and max voltage can be taken to be 40V.

Channel 2 is taken by a current clamp and is set to 100mV = 1Amp. Max current can be taken to have a reading of 1.4V (14Amps?). They are 1V increments.

The signal repeats every 4ms. (250Hz)

The time scale is 50us.

The voltage is taken across a 1 ohm resistor and the current clamp is placed before the 1 ohm resistor.

Thanks.

[image: Output Signal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note splitting pulse into 2 half triangles = 1 rectangle, 10Vp*13Ap = **130 Wp** is a rectangular pulse which is equal to area under the curve. With t=50us of rectangle or peak to nearest zero crossing   and T=4ms, T/t = 4000/50=800 thus energy in 1 ohm is 130 Wp/800 = **160 mW** average or 160mJ energy.

FYI , current must be same polarity as Voltage for R so probe orientation is reversed.  But no worries here except for measurement error.

Yet both V and I are ringing the same so it is not BW limit of probe but it should be 10V/1R = 10 A not 14A and shud be 100 W peak not 140W

( check probe load, may be defined like 1A/100mV)

- or you left scope in 10:1 mode. on by mistake.
- Does it need 50 Ohm load? that may account for calibration error.

  So current probe is not calibrated or degaussed due to DC error or hysteresis or not setup correctly.

Since I was approximating raised cosine pulse as a rectangle of DC pulse, it is 100W pk RMS in that 50us and then averaged over 4ms time should be 100W/800 = 125mW RMS of equivalent heat energy.

Conclusion

- calibrate probe.
- compute Vp*Ip and measure t from peak to nearest crossing then divide by t/T

Math functions in scopes can do the ch1*ch2 part and some do average, mean or RMS.

Also consider the **Sinc function**. y=(sin x)/x

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function